# send socket request from .net web service (asmx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I went to request to open socket from web service to be like notification when the database change . The client is request to web service when it's connection to internet to apply to web service to get his IP Address then web service can send in this IP socket when database change . And client have socket open response the request .

Code of web service in Remote host

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GetMyIpAddress()
    {
        string adree = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]; //get client request ip address
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse(adree);

            IPEndPoint remote = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, 1093);
            Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sender.Connect(remote);
            byte[] meg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test<EOF>"); // send message to client in it's ip address
            int bytesend = sender.Send(meg);
            int byterecive = sender.Receive(bytes);
            string red = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, byterecive);
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sender.Close();
            return(red);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
               return(e.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Code of client socket

```
class Program
{
    public static string data = null;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        IPHostEntry iphostinfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
       IPAddress ipaddress = iphostinfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localendpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, 1093);
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localendpoint);
            listener.Listen(10);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                Socket hander = listener.Accept();
                data = null;
                while (true)
                {
                    bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytsize = hander.Receive(bytes);
                    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytsize);
                    if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Text received : {0}", data);
               byte[] meg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                hander.Send(meg);
                hander.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                hander.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The problem when i request to web service to get my client IP address and send to this IP address for test i get this problem :

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or est ablished connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 41.218.1
>   9.226:1093

**Please help me how can solve this problem ?**

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: I bet it is the firewall at the client side that blocks the connection.

Comment: I open this port in  the client

Comment: This is not a web-service related question. This is a general networking TCP/IP socket type question. Edited tags.